# Do you earn more money on harder difficulty levels?

Tags: uncharted-3

In Uncharted 3 multiplayer (co-op in particular), do you earn more money per kill/medal/objective on the higher difficulty levels, or is it all the same and you just increase difficulty for the challenge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. While the Easy and Normal modes offer no cash multiplier, playing on Hard and Crushing gives a x1.5 and x2 multiplier respectively, so for example, a normal kill on Easy and Normal is worth $80, on Hard it's worth $120 and $160 on Crushing. Headshot kill is worth $200 on Easy and Normal and $300 and $400 on Hard and Crushing respectively. Same goes for medal rewards.

Comment: tallies with what I've found - forgot I'd even asked this! thanks

Comment: Yeah, I was looking into Uncharted 3 Q's and found a couple of unanswered ones, figured I should answer them while I'm at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Before you vote for the difficulty of a co-op arena or adventure it says:

Easy
Friendly fire: off Money : x 1

Normal
friendly fire: off Money : x 1

Hard 
friendly fire: on Money : x 1 and a half (1.5)

Crushing
friendly fire: on Money : x 2

Note: enemies wear clown masks on Crushing, not relevant to the question, but good to know. (: